# is there a tool or app out there that helps you identify the selector of an element by highlighting it?

Tags: jquery

Say you are using Chrome Developer Tools and you click on a DOM object on the screen and right click -> inspect element.

Is there any tool out there that helps you figure out what the unique selector is for that element?

For example, I need to select the highlighted DOM element below, but it becomes difficult when the DOM is complex like that:

[image]

Comment: The input has a class you can select by

Comment: @Anagio it has a class, `$('input.k-input')`  Getting EVERY selector for EVERY ancestor is a bit daunting.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss OP said they needed to select the highlighted input tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox has a Page Inspector tool for this that I find extremely helpful. Bring up your page, hit Ctrl-Shift-I, and then select an element on the page. A toolbar containing the element selected and all its ancestors are revealed.

ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector (you can see the toolbar I mentioned right above where the markup is displayed)

Answer (score 0):

For that specific piece of html :

```
var fld = $('input[data-text-field="NameFirstInitLast"]');
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides a lot of trial and error... try this.

I don't typically send people to w3schools, but theirs is the most concise "cheat sheet" reference I've found to guide me to the appropriate selectors:

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp

Keep hitting *Next Chapter* and you'll go through:

- selectors
- events
- effects
- css
- traversing
- ajax
- and some misc stuff

Print it out and read in the small room when you must.

Answer (score 0):

You can get an extension for Chrome called CSS Selector Tester it's similar to developer tool but will show you the selector for an element. Another extension is called Selector Assistant
 which is also similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can click an element in chrome tools "Elements" tab (or right-click and select Inspect) then reference it via `$0` in the Chrome console. Whichever element is highlighted will be `$0` in the console.

Since you can wrap a dom element with jquery you can do `$($0)` in the console to get the jquery element. That doesn't help too much with getting the selector, but if you were trying to debug an element in the console that is an easy way to do it.